# Using nested dataframes with databricks-connect>13.x

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

We needed to move to databricks-connect>13.x. Now I facing the issue that when I work with a nested dataframe of the structure

```
root
|-- a: string (nullable = true)
|-- b: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |-- c: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- f: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- g: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- h: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- supplier_id: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- i: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- j: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- k: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- l: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- m: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- n: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- o: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- p: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- q: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- r: boolean (nullable = true)
|-- s: integer (nullable = true)
|-- t: string (nullable = true)
```

I get the error on the cluster (13.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.4.1, Scala 2.12):

```
Caused by: grpc_shaded.com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message had too many levels of nesting.  May be malicious.  Use CodedInputStream.setRecursionLimit() to increase the depth limit.
```